# TS warning when dependency using different Anchor version

Tags: anchor, typescript

What is the canonical way to deal with a dependency using an older Anchor version? Basic example:

```
import { SomeDependency } from "deps/blahblah/packages/some-dependency/src";

export const someFunction = async (
  program: Program<SomeDependency>,
) => {
  // Here we get a very long error about how Program<SomeDependency> doesn't match Program<SomeDependency>
  let x = program;
}
```

It works fine with a simple `// @ts-ignore` above any use of `program`, but this feels like a clunky solution.

Comment: If you want to use an older version of a dependency, generally you can specify which version you want to use in the package-lock.json or yarn-lock.json file depending on if you use npm or yarn

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by rebuilding the dependency. If the idl at the imported source is outdated, you can encounter errors like this, `anchor build` the dependency to update the idl with any changes and it should resolve.